# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key using images in parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, nsunknownkeyexception

I'm trying to upload a photo to Parse and I am getting a strange error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<PFQuery 0xbe68310> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key profilePic.'
```

I can't figure out why this is happening though. Heres the code.

```
- (IBAction)setProfilePressed:(id)sender {


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Cards"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"name"]];


    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"male_user_icon.png"];


    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"male_user_icon.png" data:imageData];
    [imageFile saveInBackground];


    [query setValue:imageFile forKey:@"profilePic"];


}
```

The profilePic type is set to "File" and I am uploading a PFFile so i don't understand what the problem is. Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Did you bind profilePic as key in the xib??

Comment: Please [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key). There are countless topics covering this issue.

Comment: It simply says key `profilePic` doesn't exist, did you try to `[query  includeKey:@"profilePic"]` before setting the value for it?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if dictionary doesn't contain that `key value`.In your case may be there is `no key`  as `profilePic` for `PFQuery class` or dictionary.

Comment: It is a column in my Parse database though, even when i "includeKey" as prolilePic it still gives the same error.